# Store boto3 session object in Django Session

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, boto3, django-sessions

I am trying to store boto3 session object in Django session so that I can reuse that same object as long Django session is available.
This saves Auth requests for each operation I perform using boto3.

```
boto3_session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=request.POST.get("access_key"),
                              aws_secret_access_key=request.POST.get("secret_key"))
if not 'boto3_session' in request.session or not request.session['boto3_session']:
    request.session['boto3_session'] = boto3_session
```

I am getting error

```
TypeError: Session(region='eu-west-1') is not JSON serializable
```

Details of boto3 session

```
ipdb> dir(boto3_session)
ipdb> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_loader', '_register_default_handlers', '_session', '_setup_loader', 'client', 'events', 'get_available_partitions', 'get_available_regions', 'get_available_resources', 'get_available_services', 'get_credentials', 'profile_name', 'region_name', 'resource', 'resource_factory']
```

Trying to get dict for the object

```
ipdb> boto3_session.__dict__
{'_loader': <botocore.loaders.Loader object at 0x104502450>, 'resource_factory': <boto3.resources.factory.ResourceFactory object at 0x1045023d0>, '_session': <botocore.session.Session object at 0x1044c6f50>}
```

When I try to save above dict in session I get below error

```
TypeError: <botocore.loaders.Loader object at 0x109e5dd10> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I get this working. I am trying different things, but none are working so far.

Comment: You could store the key and secret key in the session instead, and create a new session.

Comment: In my current code, I am already storing key and secret in session, but for each request I have to authenticate. I want to avoid making auth calls for each request.

Comment: Auth isn't a separate request, it's baked into each one.